# Can I Sunder Worn Armor in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

In D&D 3.5, Sunder checks explicitly could not be made against armor worn by an opponent. However, I cannot seem to discern if this rule is still part of *Pathfinder*, so my question is a simple one: **Can the Sunder combat maneuver target armor being worn by a creature in Pathfinder?**

Please cite sources; remember that FAQ is RAW in *Pathfinder*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  In 3.5 the [sunder special attack wording](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#sunder) is "You can use a melee attack with a slashing or bludgeoning weapon to strike a weapon or shield that your opponent is holding." In Pathfinder however [it was changed to say](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder) "You can attempt to sunder an item held or worn by your opponent in place of a melee attack." Discussion by users on the Paizo forums about this note it as a change and that "yay, it makes sunder more viable," with no one bringing up objections that it can't be done for some other reason.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. [The Pathfinder rules read](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder):

> You can attempt to sunder an item held *or worn* by your opponent in place of a melee attack.

Emphasis mine.